# Delete an entire array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, csv

I'm trying to find out if I can delete an array with a method called on itself.  `array.clear` removes all elements, but not the array itself.

### Context

Here is the context. I have a CSV file with no headers. I want to be able to delete a row given one value in the row. So, the user can pass me "Chocolate", I seach the CSV and delete the row with Chocolate as the first value.

CSV file

```
Chocolate, some description blah
Cheese, some description about this one
```

Ruby file

```
require 'csv'

def remove_recipe(recipe_name)
  CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, w+) do |row|
    row.clear??? if row[0] == recipe_name
  end
end
```

I could add a header but I'd like to know if it's possible without.

Ok, to describe the input and output as Sawa has asked: A user will input string "Chocolate". I will search the CSV file for that string. If present, I want to update the CSV file to remove the row containing that string.

Comment: Your code does not help. Describe the input and output.

Comment: My edit undone. Do people not see that "post have been updated while you were editing" notification? :(

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I've changed it back

Comment: By the way my edit got stuck, wrapping around Sergio's edit, with edit #4 being empty. It looks like a bug on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Guy: thanks! It happens to me so often, that's it's frustrating :)

Comment: @sawa: yeah, race condition, it seems :)

Comment: to delete an array, you can assign nil to the variable (and run the garbage collector). But your questions looks more like a question "How to delete a line in a csv-file?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the CSV as an array of arrays and remove the elements you want to remove:

```
require "csv"

def remove_recipe(recipe_name)
  csv_ary = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
  cleaned_csv_ary = csv_ary.reject { |row| row[0] == recipe_name }
  # etc
end
```

Where I wrote "etc" you can use the cleaned array as you like, including converting it into a CSV string via `#to_csv` and writing it to a file.

Comment: Another option is to use `reject!` to remove them from the original array.

Comment: Absolutely, @tadman. I just figured it'd be more readable to rename the var anyway.

Comment: I think the in-place modification steers closer to the intent in the original question: Deleting rows.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm trying to change the CSV file like @Tadman says. (Rather than parse the file into an array, check the array, update it and then rewrite the CSV file). `reject!` doesn't let me change the CSV file? (I suppose because of CSV.read..)

Comment: You can't avoid "parsing the file into an array", that's just how the CSV library works, and how Ruby works in general. You'll need to `reject!` and then re-write the file. Altering the array doesn't alter the source of that array, you need to explicitly write it out again.

Comment: As @tadman says, you can't just delete a row in the file and have all the following rows just "move one up" - that's not physically possible. You have to read the data into memory and flow them back down onto disk without the row in question. You could truncate the existing file to the row before the deleted row and stream the rest of the rows back out.

Comment: Finally I'll add that you should, generally speaking, not load the entire CSV into an array all at once, unless the file is guaranteed to be small in all cases. You should load a block of data from the file at once and process that way. Say you load 1k of data, you then read forward in the file until you reach the next EOL. Remember your location in the file, process the 1k + extra up to EOL, go back to the file and do it again..

Comment: @SteveMidgley Eh, if your machine has multiple GB of memory and the files are unlikely to be that big, who cares? If it is too big you'll want to look at streaming it in line by line instead of chunking it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to update the CSV file, then this is the cleanest solution I could come up with:

```
require "csv"

def remove_recipe(name)
  rows = CSV.read('test.csv')
  rows.reject! { |r| r[0] == name }
  out = rows.inject([]) { |csv, row| csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join("")
  File.open('test.csv', 'w+') { |file| file.write(out) }
end

remove_recipe('Chocolate')
```